# HTML Loader not working on certain pages

Tags: javascript, html, preloader

I am designing a website and am having some issues on certain computers. Most computers show the site perfectly, but certain computers just load a blank grey screen.

My work computer is one that has an issue, 
The website is http://holidayinnkilgoretx.com and loads fine on the home page and photo page, but when I go to http://holidayinnkilgoretx.com/raa.php it messes up. Please let me know If i have something wrong in my code which is causing this. I checked all divs and closing tags etc.

It also only has the issue in google chrome.

Thank You

Comment: Works fine on `32.0.1700.107 m`. Maybe try changing the `DOCTYPE` to loose: `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
            "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">`

Comment: have you tried both with and without www. and also does this happen when on your work network or at home as well?

Comment: Also, read this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10695620/head-appears-empty-in-chrome/10695856#10695856

Comment: if you take a look in your browser console, there is a JavaScript error. As your pre-loader is removed using JavaScript, this syntax error could cause the hiding of the pre-loader event not to fire. Take a look at fixing that then update if you are still having the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the following load errors from Google developer tools which you should look into:

Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://holidayinnkilgoretx.com/js/jquery.imagesloaded.min.js".

1. raa.php:315
   Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
2. js/jquery.imagesloaded.min.js:1
   event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.
3. jquery.min.js:5
   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'create' of undefined